# PostgreSQL: Recommended way of user creation/management for development, test and production. I use Ruby on Rails

Tags: security, users, role

I am trying to think of the best (aka recommended or common professional practice) way to create users/roles in PostgreSQL database for development, test and production environments.

I have to say that I use Ruby on Rails if that matters to the answers.

Often I find information that suggests in general the following steps after the installation of PostgreSQL (on Ubuntu 14.04):

- create a role for development and a role for test with permissions `createdb`, `login` and a `password`
- use those roles (i.e. users) in database configuration files (for connections strings for example)

I wonder whether that is the secure way to go. The users would be able to create/delete databases/tables at will then, isn't that right?

What if I only want to give them read/write access to only the tables that matter for development and test respectively?
And if I go this way any ideas about administration overhead or automizations?

I work alone on the project at the moment, but other developers might join later and I care to have the databases as secure as possible.

I also need to have an idea how to deal with production later. I intend to use Heroku as service provider, so probably some configuration will be given. Anyone experience with that?

Comment: Is it possible to use different databases entirely?

Comment: Yes, possible. I chose PostgreSql because it was db of choice at Heroku. But any open source software should do.

Comment: No, I mean having separate Postgres instances for testing and production.

Comment: Actually, yes. One for development and local test. Another test for CI (Travis CI). And a production database.